# Which SQL Argument to the WHERE operation do I give to select all?

Tags: php, sql

I am currently taking info from HTML Selection which looks somewhat like this:

```
                      <select id = "select_something">
                        <option value = "All">All</option>
                        <option value = "First">Option 1</option>
                        <option value = "Second">Option 2</option> 
                        <option value = "Third">Option 3</option>  
                      </select>
```

My sql query in php looks like this:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `column` = '$something'";
```

Which argument can I enter instead of ***$something*** to get all the possible results in case "All" has been chosen?

I DO NOT want to create a different query in case "All" was selected, nor do I want to change the $query statement at all!
I am only interested in an argument for the WHERE operation which gives all results (or basically you can say it ignores the where).

Thanks in advance,
Jacob.

EDIT:
Solution found:

```
if ($something== "All") $something = 1;
else $something = "`column` = '$something'";
$query = "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE $something;
```

Thanks for everyone who replyed.

Comment: Why don't you want to change the base query?

Comment: there is no such value, you either get all with one query, or get filtered results with another query

Comment: I don't wanna change the query because I have many more selections to take into account, and I cannot create any possible query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `column` = '$something'" . (($something == "All") ? " OR 1 = 1" : "");
```

Comment: And what is doing exactly?

Comment: This one was extremely helpful!

Comment: he/she says : `I am only interested in an argument for the WHERE operation which gives all results` , that's why i added the `OR 1 = 1` to show all entries if `$something == 1` !

Comment: @JacobCohen, happy that help. don't forget to [marker my answer as the good one](http://stackoverflow.com/about) ! thanks

Comment: if ($something== "All") $something = 1;
 else $something = "`column` = '$something'";
 $query = "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE $something;

This is how I've done it, thanks to your idea.
Now I can add the AND and keep doing it for other arguments and WHERE 1 AND 1 AND 1 will do what I intended.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE 1";
```

But I also strongly suggest to read up on SQL injection and PDO.

Comment: Are you suggesting that someone may, by using javascript console for example, change the value of the selection and then send it to the server?

In that case, what would you suggest?

Comment: Yes, exactly. If you just insert the variables you get from the ``<select>`` tag, anyone could easily gain access to - or destroy - your entire database. As a bare minimum, you should use a function such as ``mysql_real_escape_string``, but really, PDO or MySQLi are far better choices. I highly recommend googling to learn about them. Security is always nice! :)

Comment: Just wondering... If I put the tags '' between a php variable, for example: WHERE `cloumn` = '$string', doesn't it protect it from anything but the tag ' itself?

Comment: Look at it this way: if you have a line ``SELECT * FROM table WHERE column = '$string'``, anyone could change the selection value and send this, for instance: ``'; DROP database;``. Then, the full SQL would be ``SELECT * FROM table WHERE column = ''; DROP database;'``. First, it would perform the SELECT. Then, it would execute ``DROP database;``, and finally, it would ignore the ending ``'``. I'm sure you can see why this is very, very unsafe.

Comment: So basically all I'll have to do is replace any ' with \' and I'm safe!

Comment: Best case, yes. But things are seldom that easy. There's a reason that the PHP MySQL extension has been deprecated starting from PHP 5.5. If you don't want to change your code or learn PDO/MySQLi, that's perfectly fine. Just please be aware that it's very easy to make mistakes that allow for various kinds of database intrusion, and that your code may not be secure.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form method="POST">
<select id = "select_something">
<option value = "1">All</option>
<option value = "2">Option 1</option>
<option value = "3">Option 2</option> 
<option value = "4">Option 3</option>  
</select>
<input type="submit" name="Submit">
</form>
```

Then we process your $_POST by:

```
if (isset($_POST['select_something'])){
  $Method = NULL;
 switch ($_POST['select_something']){
    case 1:
       $Method = "All";
       break;
    case 2:
        $Method = "Option1";
        break;
    case 3:
        $Method = "Option2";
        break;
     case 4:
        $Method = "Option3";
        break;
 }
  $Query = "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `column`=".$Method;
}
```